# OSX + Apache2 + httpd.conf + hosts + .htaccess = not working

Tags: macos, .htaccess, apache2, httpd.conf, hosts

On my Mac, I'm trying to activate htaccess rewrite rules on a local php project. Here's my configuration :

I'm using OSX 10.6.7, Apache2 is running, Php5 is activated.

My project location: /Library/WebServer/Documents/my-project/

**httpd.conf**

```
[...]
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
[...]
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/my-project/"
    ServerName my-project.local
</VirtualHost>
```

**my_user_name.conf**

```
<Directory "/Users/my_user_name/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 my-project.local
```

**.htaccess (/Library/WebServer/Documents/my-project/.htaccess) **

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\.home\.html$ front/content/home.php?rub=$1 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-[a-z0-9A-Z'_%?éèàêâûô\-]+\.html$ front/content/article.php?id=$1&rub=$2 [L]
[...]
```

But, when I try to access :

http://my-project.local/66-75-one-great-page.html

It don't resolve as :

http://my-project.local/front/content/article.php?id=66&rub=75

Rhhaaa, any ideas ?
Thx you guys :-)

Comment: **.htaccess**: /Library/WebServer/Documents/my-project/.htaccess

Comment: ...and there's nothing special in the logs. Damn! I just don't get it... :-/ Thx for your answer...

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the trailing slash after the site name in rewrite rule. Change the rewrite rule as below and try :

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)\.home\.html$ front/content/home.php?rub=$1 
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-[a-z0-9A-Z'_%?éèàêâûô\-]+\.html$ front/content/article.php?id=$1&rub=$2 [L]
```